# Most Performant SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
item_id (decimal), key_name (varchar), key_string_value (varchar)
```

It is populated with hundreds and thousands of rows. Below are the first 6 rows to give you an idea of the data.

```
 1. 1              product              product1
 2. 1              topic                topic1
 3. 1              segment              segment1
 4. 2              product              product2
 5. 2              topic                topic1
 6. 2              segment              segment1
```

Each distinct `item_id` has 3 rows associated with it and describing it with metadata like topic, product, segment. I am trying to write a SQL query which does the following and performs extremely well.

Now I need to select all item_ids which will suffice a certain combination of these metadata for example:

- get me all `item_id`'s for which `topic='topic1'` and `product='product2'` and `segment='Segment1'`

I am trying both self joins and correlated queries but am not sure which direction should I continue for the best performance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This depends on the RDBMS you are using - what is optimal for MySQL might not be optimal for MSSQL etc. Additionally, it is important to know, which indices exist, and if they are clustered. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?  Does it have any (other) indexes? Are `key_string_value`s for the same key name mostly different, or are most drawn from a small number of alternatives?

Comment: @Eugen: We will end up using Oracle for this. For now we are testing on MySQL. There is a primary key which is simply an autonumbered id column. There is composite index on key_value and key_string_value.

Comment: @John: There is a primary key which is simply an autonumbered id column. There is composite index on key_value and key_string_value. The key_string_value can be drawn from a large set of values(running in thousands). We are in development and can make enhancements to the table. I was wanting to start with a SQL involving conditions for three key_name and then expand it to more and watch for performance.

Comment: Your (performance) tests on MySQL are meaningless if you are going to run this on Oracle later

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HAVING` and conditional aggregation for this:

```
SELECT item_id
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN key_name = 'topic' AND key_string_value ='topic1' THEN 1 END) = 1
  AND  MAX(CASE WHEN key_name = 'product' AND key_string_value ='product2' THEN 1 END) = 1
  AND  MAX(CASE WHEN key_name = 'segment' AND key_string_value ='segment1' THEN 1 END) = 1
```

Is it the most performant? Will have to test, but I'd expect it to beat self-joins and correlated subqueries.

Comment: The query ran like a charm and returned result in 0.5 seconds. I will continue working on it but this is a solid start to the direction I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Forexlead My pleasure, be sure to check the query plan for index suggestions too.  I don't think you'll find a faster method, but you may improve the performance of this method through indexing.

Comment: Hi Hart, Now only if I can make this a bit more complex. Lets say I have to query only on topic and product but then have to order by segment and another key_name, how can I do that? So lets say the table has another key_name for each item_id called collection.

Comment: @Forexlead I'd probably create a new question for that, it sounds like a fairly different question than this one.  If it's just for ordering though, you can use conditional statements in your `ORDER BY`, but I'm not fully clear on what the result would look like.  If you do create a new question, some sample data and desired output should get an answer quickly.  Also, for this new question the database you're using might make a difference, so I'd add a tag for that.

Comment: I was wondering about the same but becoz it is the same DB table that I am talking about, I thought I ask it here. Anyways opening a new question now.

Answer (score 1):

Correlated subqueries are usually about the least performant solution to any problem unless the DB can transform them into joins, as some query planners can do in some cases.  In any optimization process, though, it is wise to check and compare the plans the DB actually comes up with for different queries and different conditions, using the DB's mechanism for that (e.g. `EXPLAIN PLAN` in some databases).

My first pass at this task would take this form:

```
SELECT product.item_id
FROM
  (
    SELECT item_id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE key_name = 'product' AND key_string_value = 'product2'
  ) product
  JOIN (
    SELECT item_id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE key_name = 'topic' AND key_string_value = 'topic1'
  ) topic
    ON product.item_id = topic.item_id
  JOIN (
    SELECT item_id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE key_name = 'segment' AND key_string_value = 'segment1'
  ) segment
    ON topic.item_id = segment.item_id
```

That assumes the table has a primary key constraint -- or at least a uniqueness constraint -- on `(item_id, key_name)`; if it doesn't then the inline views should use `SELECT DISTINCT`.  Additionally, it may benefit significantly from an index on `(key_name)`, or even more from an index on `(key_name, key_string_value)`.

Before you go crazy creating indexes, though, be sure you understand that though they *may* speed queries, they *do* slow inserts, updates, and deletes, and they increase the footprint of your database.  And again, check the query plans, and **test** the performance.

**Update**:
Given that we now find there is indeed an index on `(key_name, key_string_value)`, and that the wide variety of `key_string_value`s makes such an index highly selective, I'm inclined to think that the above approach will do quite well.  When you test, don't forget to `SELECT DISTINCT` if you cannot otherwise rely on the inline views to avoid providing duplicate `item_id`s.

Comment: The query is functional but is taking around 25 seconds to return. To be fair, I still need to add the primary key constraint. I already have a composite index on (key_name, key_string_value) in place. I will run the test tomorrow after adding the constraint. Will get back tomorrow.

Comment: I cannot have a PK on a composite of item_id and key_name as there can be multiple rows with the same item_id and key_name values having different values in key_string_value. I have all the indexes in place though. I will continue to look into if there are ways to make this more performant.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I don't think this has a well-performing solution without an index on `item_id`, so I think you should change your PK to a composite of `(item_id, key_name)` - you need this to be unique anyway.

Assuming you have done so, we now have a fast track to both `item_id` and `key_name`, which I consider to be a necessity.

We can now try a self join, which should give good results on MySQL, as in InnoDB all composite indices are clustered:

```
SELECT
  one.item_id 
FROM table_name AS one
INNER JOIN table_name AS two 
  ON two.item_id=one.item_id
INNER JOIN table_name AS three 
  ON three.item_id=one.item_id
WHERE one.key_name='product'
AND one.key_string_value='product1'
AND two.key_name='topic'
AND two.key_string_value='topic1'
AND three.key_name='segment'
AND three.key_string_value='segment1'
;
```

It is important to apply the selector with the highest selectivity to the driving table. i.e. `one` - in my query I have assumed, that `product` has a higher selectivity than `topic` or `segment`.

Comment: I already have an index on item_id. I cannot have a PK on a composite of item_id and key_name as there can be multiple rows with the same item_id and key_name values having different values in key_string_value. So far HAVING and conditional aggregation seems to be the best performing.

Comment: @Forexlead you should update your question to mention, that there might be more than one value for an item_id/key_name pair - this is a game changer!